# My PID using which CPU?

Tags: process, cpu

I have a ubuntu box in which contains 4 CPU's (0,1,2,3). Let's say If i hit a webservice, that is taking some time to get the output (2 min). Let's say my webservice PID is xxxx , I want to check this process is using which CPU (0/1/2/3 ?) Can someone tell me i can check this by which command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `ps -aF` . Here **PSR** number shoes processor number process is currently assigned to

> psr        PSR     processor that process is currently assigned to.

```
$ ps -aF
UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
arushir+  7183  6916  0 12382  6884   0 10:51 pts/19   00:00:00 ssh arushi.rai@localhost
arushir+  8672  5820  0  9341  3224   3 11:55 pts/2    00:00:00 ps -aF
```

Or you can get the processor of a pid directly , using
    **ps -q  -o psr**

```
$ ps -q 7810 -o psr
PSR
  2
```